# RegEx: Detect string interpolation but not inside attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, string-interpolation

I am working on creating Web Components and I need a Regular Expression that captures instances of string interpolation in a template sting.
For example with the following string:

`<img src="${this.image}"/><h5>${this.title}</h5><p>${this.description}</p>`

The instances of string interpolation are inside `${}` and can be captured with: `(this(\.\w+))`.
But I do not want to capture the first instance because it is inside an attribute.

I have tried the expression `((?<!".+)this(\.\w+)+(?!.+"))` which works with a multiline string (each tag on own line) but now on a single line.

[Here is my RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/74ufu).
Perhaps someone with more exp in RegEx can help me out.

### Edit

To keep the question simple and to the point I didn't mention this...

The reason I want to do this is because I have am using [Lit](https://lit.dev) to create Web Components, I have already created an interpolator function that returns a [Lit TemplateResult](https://lit.dev/docs/api/templates/), now I want highlight data with `<b>` tags so I want to replace RexEx matches with the [unsafeHTML directive](https://lit.dev/docs/api/templates/), but unsafeHTML throws an error when inside attributes.
Here is my interpolator function:

```
export function FillTemplate(templateString: string, data: any): TemplateResult {
    let regex = /((?<!".+)this(\.\w+)+(?!.+"))/g;
    if (regex.test(templateString)) {
        templateString = templateString.replace(/((?<!".+)this(\.\w+)+(?!.+"))/g, "unsafeHTML($1)");
    }
    return new Function('html', 'unsafeHTML', "return html`"+templateString +"`;").call(data, html, unsafeHTML);
};
```

.... I will also give this a think, maybe it's better for me to test the object keys and not the template string...

Comment: something like ... [`/(?<!=["'])\$\{this\.(?<key>[^}]+)\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/X0TuLw/1) ... utilizes a [negative lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind to account for a quoted attribute: `?<!=["'])\$\{this(?:\.\w+)+\}`. This will exclude the `src="${this.image}"` in your example, but you'll get a false positive for HTML text, such as `<p>Quote: "${this.quote}"</p>`

You can use a negative lookbehind to account for a quoted attribute in an HTML tag: `(?<!<\w+ (\w+=["'][^"']*["'] )*\w+=["'])\$\{this(?:\.\w+)+\}`.

Here is an example with both regexes:

```js
const regex1 = /(?<!["'])\$\{this(?:\.\w+)+\}/g;
const regex2 = /(?<!<\w+ (\w+=["'][^"']*["'] )*\w+=["'])\$\{this(?:\.\w+)+\}/g;

[
  '<img src="${this.image}"/><h5>${this.title}</h5><p>${this.description}</p><p>Quote: "${this.quote}"</p>',
  '<img foo="bar" src="${this.image}"/><h5>${this.title}</h5><p>${this.description}</p><p>Quote: "${this.quote}"</p>'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log('- regex1:', str.match(regex1));
  console.log('- regex2:', str.match(regex2));
});
```

Explanation of `regex2`:

- `(?<!` -- negative lookbehind start
- `<\w+`  -- start of HTML tag and space `<img`
- `(\w+=["'][^"']*["'] )*` -- 0+ attributes of form `attr="value"` , with trailing space
- `\w+=["']` -- attribute start, such as `src="` or `src='`
- `)` -- negative lookbehind end
- `\$\{this` -- literal `${this`
- `(?:\.\w+)+` -- non-capture group for 1+ patterns of `.something`
- `\}` -- literal `}`

**Note:** If your regex engine does not support negative lookbehind (notably Safari) you can change that to a capture group, and restore it with a `.replace()`

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as it is the most comprehensive and explains to expression.
Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:

`[^"]\$\{(this\.\w+)`

This will only take interpolations that are not preceded by `"`

Answer (score 1):

This one *will* account for attributes too (contrary to what's asked).
An alternative solution, instead of Regex, (and if you trust the `data`) would be using the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) and let the JavaScript's parser interpret and evaluate the string as Template Literal and do the desired job for you:

```js
const interpolate = (str, data) =>
  Function("return (`" + str + "`);").call(data);


// Use like:
const str = '<img src="${this.image}"/><h5>${this.title}</h5><p>${this.description}</p>';

const data = {
  title: "Lorem ipsum",
  description: "Dolor sit amet",
  image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH7ZS.jpg?s=64&g=1",
};

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", interpolate(str, data));
```

Additionally, if you find the `this` in your template overly repetitive you could use the **Object keys directly**, and [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the values, like in this solution:

```js
const interpolate = (str, data) =>
  Function(...Object.keys(data), "return (`" + str + "`);").apply(null, Object.values(data));


// Use like:
const str = '<img src="${image}"/><h5>${title}</h5><p>${description}</p>';

const data = {
  title: "Lorem ipsum",
  description: "Dolor sit amet",
  image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH7ZS.jpg?s=64&g=1",
};

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", interpolate(str, data));
```

or, similar as above (without the `this`, by using the Object keys) without unsafe evaluation, would be by using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a Regex like `/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g`:

```js
const interpolate = (str, data) =>
  str.replace(/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g, (_, k) => data[k]);

const str = '<img src="${image}"/><h5>${title}</h5><p>${description}</p>';
const data = {
  title: "Lorem ipsum",
  description: "Dolor sit amet",
  image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH7ZS.jpg?s=64&g=1",
};

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", interpolate(str, data));
```

Comment: +1 for using my image and for the `interpolate` function. However I have created a function that is returning a [LitElement TemplateResult](https://lit.dev/docs/api/templates/)... I will update my question to show my function

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`[^="]{2}\${(\S+?)}`

1. Attributes always will have a `=` and their value will be in quotes. So `[^="]{2}` ensures that we match the two characters that are anything but `=` and `"`.
2. `(\S+?)` then lazily captures the required data in a capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NxChel/1)

Comment: `[^=][^"]` would be more accurate than `[^="]{2}`, and exclude `==`, `"=` for example